# What is the best way to fetch Tree/Hierarchical structure data from Oracle

Tags: oracle, tree, hierarchical-data

I want to fetch Hierarchical/Tree data something like below from a Table which has following definiton.

```
Tree Table:
"""""""""""
Id   |ParentId
"""""""""""
Work1|null
Work2|Work1
Work3|Work2
...
```

Required Query result Data (no need to be tabbed)- If I Pick 'Work1' I should complete Ids which are under its root something like below. If I pick 'Work2' then also I should complete Ids above and below its root.

```
> Work1 
----------
>   Work2
----------
>     Work3
---------
```

I used below query but it is giving me duplicate records.

```
select Id from TreeTable start with Id in ('Work1','Work2') connect by nocycle Parentid=prior Id or Id = prior Parentid
```

*Note: I want to get the data within a **SINGLE QUERY** (optimized) way*

Thanks and Regards,
PV.

Comment: Why do you need both: `Parentid=prior Id or Id = prior Parentid` ????????

Comment: if i am not using both I am not getting root nodes .

Comment: For ex: If i pick Work2 then I will not get Work1 but i will only get Work3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  id
FROM    q
START WITH
        id IN ('Work1', 'Work2')
CONNECT BY
        parent = PRIOR id
        AND id NOT IN ('Work1', 'Work2')
```

This condition:

```
AND id NOT IN ('Work1', 'Work2')
```

will cut off the branches already selected with `START WITH`.

Comment: the query you suggested will assure me that it will start with values in the START WITH IN Clause and gets entire tree (top and bottom) for 'Work1' (firt value in IN clause), and then when it tries to fetch for 'Work2' (seconf value in IN clause) it see if it is alreary there 'Work1' tree it will skip that value and proceeds with next...PLEASE comment on my assumptions

Comment: @Srinivas: it will start to fetch the tree starting from `1` and will stop on `2`. Then it will fetch entire tree starting from `2`. Just add `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(id)` into the query, it will become more clear.

Comment: Last Question - I think this is the best way of handling this case or do you think there are any other improvments which we can make?

Comment: @Srinivas: think it's the best.

Comment: @Quassnoi-- sorry to ask again...when i tried this on a table which has 7000 rows (all one under one...mean all come under a single parent)...the query is taking lot of time...all env. conditions are good...is there a way thru which we can improve?

Comment: @Srinivas: create an index on `parent`

Comment: @Quassnoi-- table already has an index on parent and child :(

Comment: @Quassnoi- another issue if 'root node' is not avialable in IN clause entire tree is not fetched.

Comment: @Srinivas: please post it as another question